# Link in a javascript created image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to generate a link into my javascript generated image.

```
<div id="wrapper"></div> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var divWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var image = document.createElement('img'); 
    image.src = 'image.png'; 
    image.height = 100; 
    image.width = 50; 
    image.style.position = "absolute";         
    image.style.left = 60 + "px";         
    image.style.top = 32 + "px";  
    document.write("<a href="index.php">); //HERE MIGHT BE THE MISTAKE
    divWrapper.appendChild(image);
  </script>`
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you look up the use of `document.write()`.

Comment: btw you have unclosed quotes and unescaped ones in that row

Comment: Well, `document.write("<a href="index.php">);` is a syntax error; it should be `document.write("<a href=\"index.php\">");`. Search _string concatenation_ and _escaping quotes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `document.write()`. Create a new a element like you created the image and append the image to the anchor element and the anchor element to the wrapper.

```js
//define elements
var divWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var image = document.createElement('img');
var a = document.createElement('a');

//set image attributes
image.src = 'image.png';
image.height = 100;
image.width = 50;
image.style.position = "absolute";
image.style.left = 60 + "px";
image.style.top = 32 + "px";

//set anchor attributes
a.href = "index.php";

//Append the elements
a.appendChild(image);
divWrapper.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Also the quotation is wrong in `document.write("<a href="index.php">);` this should have been `document.write("<a href=\"index.php\">");` because you need to escape double quotes if you use them inside a string defined with double quotes.